How to fix the status button appearing in the tasks column
The problem: I'm trying to make the status button appear in the respective column but failed.
Image of the table
Steps taken:
just to let you know, the Task column was added manually, here is the table:
<asp:Table ID="Group" runat="server" CssClass="table table-bordered text-center task-table">
    <asp:TableHeaderRow ID="GroupHeaderRow">
        <asp:TableHeaderCell CssClass="text-center task-header-cell rounded-start-4" ColumnSpan="2">Task</asp:TableHeaderCell>
    </asp:TableHeaderRow>
    <asp:TableRow Style="border-left: 2px solid #ABCDFD; z-index: 1000;">
        <asp:TableCell Width="50px" CssClass="task-text-box-input-cell">
            <asp:TextBox ID="taskTextBox" runat="server" CssClass="task-text-box form-control" placeholder="Enter Task" OnTextChanged="AddTask" UseSubmitBehavior="false"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>

I am checking the data type of the column stored in the database:
Screenshot of SQL Server table consisting of the columns,
and adding the data from the DB respectively:
Screenshot of data in the SQL Server table
I've tried:

adding the TableRow multiple times to the table i.e. Group.Rows.Add(tableRow) (Group is the name of my Table)
adding the TableRow one time at the end i.e. after the cells and rows were added
making multiple TableRow and TableCell for both the task and status

and none of these worked.
The code:
protected void UpdatedUpdateTable()
{
    const string connectionString = "Data Source=localhost;Initial Catalog=sunday.com;Integrated Security=True;Encrypt=False";
    int user_id = Convert.ToInt32(Session["UserId"]);                        

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        string getColumnsQuery = "SELECT * FROM columnsOfTables WHERE user_id = @user_id";

        using (SqlCommand getColumnsCommand = new SqlCommand(getColumnsQuery, connection))
        {
            connection.Open();

            getColumnsCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", user_id);

            using (SqlDataReader reader = getColumnsCommand.ExecuteReader())
            {
                // Clear the space for the updated rows excluding the taskTextBox
                for (int i = Group.Rows.Count - 1; i > 1; i--)
                {
                    Group.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
                }

                while (reader.Read())
                {                            
                    TableRow tableRow = new TableRow();
                    TableCell tableCell = new TableCell();

                    string dataType = reader.GetString(3);

                    if (dataType.Equals("Task"))
                    {
                        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                        {
                            connection1.Open();

                            string query = "SELECT * FROM dataOfTables WHERE user_id = @user_id AND board_id = @board_id AND data_type = @data_type";

                            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection1))
                            {
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", user_id);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@board_id", this.getBoardId());
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_type", "Task");

                                using (SqlDataReader taskReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    while (taskReader.Read())
                                    {
                                        string task = taskReader["data"].ToString();

                                        TextBox textBoxWithTask = new TextBox();
                                        textBoxWithTask.ID = $"task-textbox-{taskReader["id"].ToString()}";
                                        textBoxWithTask.Text = task;
                                        textBoxWithTask.CssClass = "task-text-box";
                                        textBoxWithTask.TextChanged += EditTask;

                                        tableCell.Controls.Add(textBoxWithTask);
                                        tableRow.Controls.Add(tableCell);                                                
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    } 
                    else if (dataType.Equals("Status"))
                    {
                        TableHeaderRow tableHeaderRow = (TableHeaderRow)Group.Rows[0];
                        bool statusHeaderExists = false;

                        foreach (TableCell cell in tableHeaderRow.Cells)
                        {
                            if (cell.Text.Equals(reader["column_name"].ToString()))
                            {
                                statusHeaderExists = true;
                                break;
                            }
                        }

                        if (statusHeaderExists == false)
                        {
                            TableHeaderCell statusHeaderCell = new TableHeaderCell();
                            statusHeaderCell.Text = reader["column_name"].ToString();
                            this.GroupHeaderRow.Cells.Add(statusHeaderCell);
                        }

                        using (SqlConnection connection1 = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                        { 
                            string query = "SELECT * FROM dataOfTables WHERE user_id = @user_id AND board_id = @board_id AND data_type = @data_type AND column_name = @column_name";

                            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(query, connection1))
                            {
                                connection1.Open();

                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user_id", user_id);
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@board_id", this.getBoardId());
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@data_type", "Status");
                                command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column_name", reader["column_name"].ToString());

                                using (SqlDataReader statusReader = command.ExecuteReader())
                                {
                                    while (statusReader.Read())
                                    {
                                        string status = statusReader["data"].ToString();

                                        HtmlGenericControl statusBtn = new HtmlGenericControl();
                                        statusBtn.InnerText = statusReader["data"].ToString();
                                        statusBtn.Attributes["id"] = $"status-btn-{statusReader["id"].ToString()}";
                                        statusBtn.Attributes["class"] = "status-btn";
                                        statusBtn.Attributes["type"] = "button";

                                        if (statusReader["data"].ToString().Equals("Done")) {
                                            statusBtn.Attributes["styles"] = "background-color: rgb(0, 200, 117)";
                                            tableCell.Style["background-color"] = "rgb(0, 200, 117)";
                                        }
                                        else if (statusReader["data"].ToString().Equals("Working on it"))
                                        {
                                            statusBtn.Attributes["styles"] = "background-color: rgb(253, 188, 100)";
                                            tableCell.Style["background-color"] = "rgb(253, 188, 100)";
                                        } 
                                        else if (statusReader["data"].ToString().Equals("Stuck"))
                                        {
                                            statusBtn.Attributes["styles"] = "background-color: rgb(253, 188, 100)";
                                            tableCell.Style["background-color"] = "rgb(253, 188, 100)";
                                        }
                                        else
                                        {
                                            statusBtn.Attributes["styles"] = "background-color: rgb(121, 126, 147)";
                                            tableCell.Style["background-color"] = "rgb(121, 126, 147)";
                                        }

                                        tableCell.Controls.Add(statusBtn);
                                        tableRow.Controls.Add(tableCell);
                                    }
                                }

                                connection1.Close();
                            }
                        }                                
                    }

                    this.Group.Controls.Add(tableRow);
                }
            }

            HtmlGenericControl addColumnBtn = new HtmlGenericControl("button");
            addColumnBtn.Attributes["id"] = "AddColumnButton";
            addColumnBtn.Attributes["class"] = "add-column-btn";
            addColumnBtn.Attributes["type"] = "button";
            addColumnBtn.Attributes["onclick"] = "showColumnsMenu()";
            addColumnBtn.InnerText = "+";

            TableHeaderRow headerRow = (TableHeaderRow)Group.Rows[0];
            bool addColumnBtnHeaderExists = false;

            foreach (TableCell cell in headerRow.Cells)
            {
                foreach (Control control in cell.Controls)
                {
                    if (control is HtmlGenericControl btn && btn.Attributes["id"] == "AddColumnButton")
                    {
                        addColumnBtnHeaderExists = true;
                        break;
                    }
                }

                if (addColumnBtnHeaderExists)
                    break;
            }

            if (!addColumnBtnHeaderExists)
            {
                TableHeaderCell addColumnBtnHeaderCell = new TableHeaderCell();
                addColumnBtnHeaderCell.Controls.Add(addColumnBtn);
                headerRow.Cells.Add(addColumnBtnHeaderCell);
            }
        }
    }
}


I would suggest that a GridView would work rather well here.
So, say this GridView, and note the markup for a button (row click).
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1"
            runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="ID"
            CssClass="table table-hover" Width="55%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Fighter" HeaderText="Fighter" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Engine" HeaderText="Engine" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Thrust" HeaderText="Thrust (lbs)" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstFlight" HeaderText="First Flight" DataFormatString="{0:MMM dd yyyy}" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server"
                            Height="96px"
                            ImageUrl='<%# Eval("ImagePath") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Button ID="cmdView" runat="server" Text="View"
                            OnClick="cmdView_Click" CssClass="btn" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <div id="picturearea" runat="server" visible="false">

            <asp:Button ID="cmdBack" runat="server" Text="Back to Fighters"
                CssClass="btn" OnClick="cmdBack_Click" />
            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblFighter" runat="server" Text="" Font-Size="Large">
            </asp:Label>
            <br />
            Description:
            <br />
            <asp:Label ID="lblDesc" runat="server" Text="" Width="30%"
                Font-Size="Large" Font-Italic="true"></asp:Label>

            <br />
            <br />
            <asp:Image ID="iFighter" runat="server" Width="50%" />
        </div>

So, code behind to load is this:
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
            LoadGrid();
    }

    void LoadGrid()
    {
        string strSQL = "SELECT * FROM Fighters ORDER BY Thrust";

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST4))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand(strSQL, conn))
            {
                conn.Open();
                DataTable rstData = new DataTable();
                rstData.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
                GridView1.DataSource = rstData;
                GridView1.DataBind();
            }
        }
    }

And the code for the row button, which will set the image URL of the current row is this:
    protected void cmdView_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Button cmdView = (Button)sender;
        GridViewRow gRow = (GridViewRow)cmdView.NamingContainer;
        Image fImage = (Image)gRow.FindControl("Image1");

        iFighter.ImageUrl = fImage.ImageUrl;

        lblFighter.Text = gRow.Cells[0].Text;
        lblDesc.Text = gRow.Cells[4].Text;
        GridView1.Visible = false; // hide the grid view
        picturearea.Visible = true; // show picture area
    }

    protected void cmdBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView1.Visible = true; 
        picturearea.Visible = false;
    }

Note how we hide the GridView on row click, and show the div with the image that we set.
The result is thus this:

So, as you can see, we don't have a lot of markup, and we don't have a lot of code behind either.
So, I suggest using a GridView. Note how I added the bootstrap "table" and "table-hover" class to the GridView, and thus the result is a bootstrap formatted table.

Thanks for the help, though it wasn't the solution to the problem. I had forgotten that I had set the 'ColumnSpan' of the table to '2'. resulting the button appearing in the Task column

No worries, keep in mind, note how by using a GridView, then the button click is with ease able to get the "current row" click. And note how no loop is required to fill out the GridView. so, at the end of the day, I still think using a GridView is a better choice, since it ultimately less markup for you to write, has ability for a row click, and allows you to feed it a data source.
